# Are anti-affinity rules from existing pods able to prevent other deployments in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

We have a Kubernetes cluster on AWS (EKS) with several nodegroups, each running several nodes on several availability zones. On this EKS cluster we run a MongoDB cluster in nodegroup `acceptance-cluster-ng-mongo-db`. Every node in this nodegroup runs on a different availability zone.

We now want to run another MongoDB cluster in a different nodegroup (`acceptance-cluster-ng-another-mongo-db`, real name redacted). We created a completely new nodegroup on the existing availability zones. Every node in this nodegroup runs on a different availability zone, which are the same availability zones as the existing MongoDB cluster. The pods do not want to spin up however, regardless the affinity/anti-affinity rules that we use. We did tried 3 separate attemps.

For the existing MongoDB cluster we always used the following affinity/anti-affinity rules:

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name
              operator: In
              values:
                - acceptance-cluster-ng-mongo-db
  podAntiAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
            - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
              operator: In
              values:
                - mongodb
        topologyKey: "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
```

**ATTEMPT 1**

For the new MongoDB cluster we started by using the following rules:

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name
              operator: In
              values:
                - acceptance-cluster-ng-another-mongo-db
  podAntiAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
            - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
              operator: In
              values:
                - another-mongodb
        topologyKey: "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
```

This gave us the message:

`0/11 nodes are available: 3 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity rules, 3 node(s) didn't satisfy existing pods anti-affinity rules, 8 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.`

**ATTEMPT 2**

We then tried to specify a specific host (which lives in the desired nodegroup) with the following config (no anti-affinity):

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchFields:
            - key: metadata.name
              operator: In
              values:
                - ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.xxx.compute.internal
```

This gave us the message:

`0/11 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity rules, 1 node(s) didn't satisfy existing pods anti-affinity rules, 10 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.`

**ATTEMPT 3**:

We then tried to deploy without *any* affinity/anti-affinity rules. This gave us the message:

`0/11 nodes are available: 11 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity rules, 11 node(s) didn't satisfy existing pods anti-affinity rules.`

**CONCLUSION**:

So after several days of tinkering around, we are out of ideas and **we're wondering whether the first MongoDB deployment with its anti-affinity rules is bothering our second deployment**, even though the nodegroup is different and we think these rules should only apply to those specific pods of the existing Mongo cluster?

Also, I should mention that we see no taint on the nodes in nodegroup `acceptance-cluster-ng-another-mongo-db`. Each node is running on `v1.21.5-eks-9017834`

**Edit:**
Here is the describe from a pod that will not start, using the configuration which tried to run on a specific host in the desired nodegroup:

```
Name:           another-mongodb-0
Namespace:      acceptance
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=mongodb
                app.kubernetes.io/component=mongodb
                app.kubernetes.io/instance=another-mongodb
                app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb
                controller-revision-hash=another-mongodb-68b848c5f9
                helm.sh/chart=mongodb-10.0.5
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=another-mongodb-0
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/another-mongodb
Containers:
  mongodb:
    Image:      docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.4.2-debian-10-r0
    Port:       27017/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Command:
      /scripts/setup.sh
    Liveness:   exec [mongo --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:  exec [mongo --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      BITNAMI_DEBUG:                    false
      MY_POD_NAME:                      another-mongodb-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      MY_POD_NAMESPACE:                 acceptance (v1:metadata.namespace)
      K8S_SERVICE_NAME:                 another-mongodb-headless
      MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST:     another-mongodb-0.$(K8S_SERVICE_NAME).$(MY_POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
      MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME:         ANOTHER-MONGODB-ACC
      MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME:      $(MY_POD_NAME).$(K8S_SERVICE_NAME).$(MY_POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
      MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD:            <set to the key 'mongodb-root-password' in secret 'another-mongodb'>    Optional: false
      MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY:          <set to the key 'mongodb-replica-set-key' in secret 'another-mongodb'>  Optional: false
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD:             no
      MONGODB_SYSTEM_LOG_VERBOSITY:     0
      MONGODB_DISABLE_SYSTEM_LOG:       no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_IPV6:              no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_DIRECTORY_PER_DB:  no
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/mongodb from datadir (rw)
      /scripts/setup.sh from scripts (rw,path="setup.sh")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-2z5qv (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  datadir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  datadir-another-mongodb-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  scripts:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      another-mongodb-scripts
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-2z5qv:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  21s (x6 over 4m30s)  default-scheduler  0/11 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity rules, 1 node(s) didn't satisfy existing pods anti-affinity rules, 10 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.
```

**Edit:**
Here is a description of the node where we would expect the pod to run on with our specific node affinity:

````
NAME                                             STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION               LABELS
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   4d6h   v1.21.5-eks-9017834   alpha.eksctl.io/cluster-name=acceptance-cluster,alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name=acceptance-cluster-ng-another-mongo-db,beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.small,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=ON_DEMAND,eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-xxx,eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=acceptance-cluster-ng-another-mongo-db,eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateId=lt-xxx,eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateVersion=1,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=eu-central-1,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-central-1a,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.small,topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone=eu-central-1a,topology.kubernetes.io/region=eu-central-1,topology.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-central-1a```
````

Comment: Can you post `kubectl describe pod <pending pod name>` to your question?

Comment: Great idea, thank you. I've added the description to the bottom of my post.

Comment: `app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb` - should the value be `another-mongodb` to match your podAntiAffinity rule?

Comment: Yes that's true. I've been tinkering around with the settings quite a bit and this was indeed a mismatch one time. Yet the deployment that matches this description (setting affinity to a specific host) does not contain any anti-affinity rule as described above.

Comment: Can you post `kubectl get node ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.xxx.compute.internal --show-labels` to your question? The node that you purposely would like the pod to run on.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @gohm'c I've added the description of that specific node.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak we're using version 1.21.5. The cluster is being set up on AWS EKS with Ansible through Cloudformation.